# How to free memory inside a for loop of creating multiple object?

Tags: java, object, garbage-collection

Here in the below code - object s2 created 10000000 times and added inside list - samp2 which will be used somewhere outside. Will it [created objects] get GC by making it as null?

Can anyone explain about this?

If its not happening GC, then how to achieve GC , since this much object created and added in to the list and further no use ?

Kindly help me on this ?

/*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*/

```
List<SampleBean> samp2=new ArrayList<>();


for(int i=1;i<10000000;i++){

        SampleBean s2=new SampleBean();

        s2.x=i;

        samp2.add(s2);
        s2=null;
}
```

/**SampleBean Class**/

```
public class SampleBean{

  int x;

}
```

Note : samp2  is the list holding the objects and it ll be in use outside.

Comment: perhaps read a basic tutorial on garbage collection. You'll find lots if you search. I can't help note your bio states you have 3.3 years of java experience. Time to read up on garbage collection perhaps...?

Comment: Hi Jigar Joshi, thanks for ur comments. I m Currently trying to understand the Garbage collection process.For that , i m trying to dereference the objects once its used [after added in to list].For that i raised the question. Can u pls suggest some site links for the GC process along with examples ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects are only garbage collected when no other object holds any reference to it.

In that case, since you still hold a reference to samp2 which itself holds references to each of the elements, they won't be garbage collected.

Also, that

```
s2 = null;
```

is irrelevant, as s2 the variable scope is only that block. So once it gets to the end of the block, the variable ceases to exist.

If you want an object to be garbage collected you just make sure you're not holding any other references to it. In this case, you would simply remove it from the samp2 ArrayList.

Comment: Hi @manecosta ,Thanks for the info.But anyway I am not able to remove s2 objects from the samp2 arrayList ,since the arrayList required outside the loop. Is there anyother way we can achieve GC ? Any suggesstion?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want. If you need the objects inside samp2 outside the loop, why would you want them to be garbage collected? If you only need the samp2 array itself, nothing is stopping you from removing the objects inside.

Comment: Hi @manecosta, I explain my understanding here. Object for SampleBean is being created repeatedly [so many new objects & correspondingly memory for that] inside the for loop and added up in the list. Memory gets occupied for the created objects.  I m trying to free the memory created for that objects once its added up in the list .

 I want the array samp2 only once its filled with the SampleBean objects. As per ur suggestion how to remove the objects inside ?

Please Correct me if my understanding is wrong ?

Comment: You seem to want to free up the memory used by those objects but at the same time not lose the objects. Where would the objects be stored then if not in memory?